# web scraping with XML, turn td node into val

Tags: xml, r, web-scraping

I want to scrape google search for number of hits:

```
require(XML)

input <- "projektgebiet" 
url <- paste("https://www.google.at/search?q=",
             input,
             "&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:de:official&client=firefox-a",
             sep = "")

CAINFO = paste(system.file(package="RCurl"), "/CurlSSL/ca-bundle.crt", sep = "")
script <- getURL(url, followlocation = TRUE, cainfo = CAINFO)
doc <- htmlParse(script)

xmlValue(getNodeSet(doc, "//td")[[6]])
```

I'm close - the only problem is that I don't grasp how to address the two values within the node seperately - I actually just want the number.. (in the above example the two values are concatenated)

I'd also wish to know of a way how to avoid the indexing [[6]], but don't know if it is possible to address the node by any other characteristic.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

ps: of course I could use a regex - but I think this is not the most elegant way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the `[[6]]`
by noticing that one of the `div` elements has an `id` attribute.
The following returns the contents of the two child nodes, separately, 
without concatenating them.

```
xpathSApply(doc, "//div[@id='subform_ctrl']/*", xmlValue)
# [1] "Erweiterte Suche"            "Ungefähr 245.000 Ergebnisse"
```